# Bootstrap tooltip incorrect positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've just recently started using bootstrap and am working on part of my Christmas present to my girlfriend - a puzzle for her to figure out what her real present is (tickets to Hamilton in London).

However, I've run into an issue with the bootstrap tooltips. I'm expecting to see a tooltip next to the span word that is clicked, on **hover** or **click**. But for some reason the tool tip is up in the top-left of the body.

Could anyone help me out here?

Here is a pen that shows the error:
**[Link to CodePen](https://codepen.io/Todai/pen/LepGrY)**

I'm using the suggested example of initializing with:

```
 $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
```

Comment: You are using the Bootstrap 4 JS file with the Bootstrap 3 CSS file. Pick a version.

Comment: That was it, actually. God, I knew it had to be a really basic issue. I was playing around with 4 before choosing 3.

Comment: You're also using Bootstrap 4 without including Popper.js; necessary for Tooltip positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the same version of Bootstrap. Either go for v3 or v4 completely. The problem should be resolved once you use compatible files.